# Story where most of humanity was moved from Earth to two other planets

Tags: story-identification, novel

There's a story where humanity is an experiment of a robot intelligence from outer space (maybe from the center of the Galaxy, I'm not sure), I'd read this around 7-10 years ago. Said intelligence some day moves most of humanity to two other planets, where warlike civilizations emerge (they also try to reclaim the Earth at some point in the book). Those left behind develop ability to space travel without tools or anything (and, if memory serves, become immortal or very long-lived). There's also a group of Christian robots that've taken humanity's mantle of believing in God. The book ends with one of the believer robots having faith crisis over the aforementioned intelligence.

The author compares at some point humanity to a bacteria strain that was moved from one Petri dish to another - the main population keeps its properties, the leftovers mutate into something else.

The book itself didn't appear either too worn-out or freshly printed, so I'd estimate 80-s as printing period.

Comment: Any idea when you read this?

Comment: @Null Seven to ten years ago. The book itself didn't look recently-printed, so I'd estimate 80-s as writing period.

Comment: Please [edit] any additional information you can think of into your question.

Comment: Interesting. There are a lot of elements that match different stories I've read, but I don't think I've read any one story that would match. Are you sure that this was all one story, and not multiple books? (Or multiple stories in an anthology?)

Comment: @Shokhet I think it was one story.

Comment: This makes me think of Clifford D. Simak who's fond of Christian robots, but none of the plots so far quite match.
http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Creator/CliffordSimak

Comment: Dang it, @FuzzyBoots, don't forget the warning when you post a tvtropes link...  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After more research, I think this could be Clifford D. Simak's *[Choice of Gods](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/222094.A_Choice_of_Gods)*. It was first published in 1972, but [new editions are periodically released](https://www.goodreads.com/work/editions/215081-a-choice-of-gods).

> One day most of humankind disappeared. A few human beings were left on the deserted earth along with countless robots. The human beings--including a small tribe of American Indians--made do. The Indians returned to ancient tribal ways, the others stubbornly tried to rebuild technology. The robots--some stayed with the humans performing their service functions, some went off to create a religiously-based society of their own.
>
> Millennia later, a star-traveler returns from the center of the universe. The people of earth had been found and were planning to return. But something else had been found, too--the central intelligence of the universe!

You have Christian robots, transcendent humans, and a central intelligence.

Comment: That's it! Thank you.

Comment: @Michail: Glad I could help. :) Once I thought of Simak (courtesy of *Project Pope*, which I asked after on this site), I figured I'd check his other works.